# How can I pass variables from one CGI script to another?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a CGI perl script called `install-app-pl.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print header('text/html');

use strict;
use CGI ':standard';

# Get me some vars

my @params = param();

my $APP_NAME          = param('app_name');
my $APP_WEB_PORT      = param('app_web_port');
my $APP_WEB_USER      = param('app_web_user');
my $APP_WEB_PASS      = param('app_web_pass');
my $DOWNLOAD_DIR      = param('download_dir');
my $CONFIG_DIR        = param('config_dir');
my $LIBRARY_DIR       = param('library_dir');
my $TEMP_DOWNLOAD_DIR = param('temp_download_dir');

# Run another script

if ( $APP_NAME ) {
    print "Installing $APP_NAME...";
    print "<pre>";
    system ("perl /var/www/mysite.local/public_html/lib/$APP_NAME/install-$APP_NAME.pl");
    print "</pre>" ;
}
else {
    print "No app specified, check the error log";
}
```

I'm trying to get it to pass the variables defined from the CGI parameters to `install-$APP_NAME.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print header('text/html');

use strict;
use CGI ':standard';

require "/var/www/mysite.local/public_html/cgi-bin/install-app-pl.cgi"

# Echo my vars

print "$CONFIG_DIR $DOWNLOAD_DIR $LIBRARY_DIR $PGID $PUID $TZ $APP_WEB_PORT";
```

But I'm not sure of the best way to pass those on.

Comment: So you're going to execute stuff on the filesystem based on user input without thoroughly sanitizing/limiting the data? Hmm... interesting approach.

Comment: @MattJacob I'm learning CGI on a VM in a private network. I plan on learning how to limit data later. This isn't for any production system, just for my own education.

Comment: You'd pass arguments to a script the same way you'd pass arguments to any shell process. If you have a bunch of them, it might make more sense to pass a serialized representation (e.g., JSON) or use some kind of persistent storage (e.g., file, database).

Comment: If you know how to set up VMs and stuff, why bother with 20 year old CGI technology that is  outdated, complicated and very limited in what it can do? The CGI module has been removed from the Perl core and we have way better things available today, like refrigerators and chairs. I usually post a link to SawyerX's talk _CGI.pm must die_, but since I'm on my phone I leave it up to you that find it on YouTube. It's educational and funny, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: Honestly, "I plan on learning how to limit data later." is an extremely bad approach. Learn to do things the right way the first time; most often when someone does things in the manner you're suggesting, they get things 'working' and don't look back. I recommend learning proper techniques and skills from the ground up, not from top down. If you're doing this for education purposes, do it right.

Comment: @stevieb: I disagree. Did you really learn how to do *everything* properly, all at once? If so then you know much more than I do.

Comment: @stevieb so, by that logic, if I want to learn programming, I must first learn everything there is to know without doing a single exercise or simple project?

Comment: I guess I'll try not ask questions trying to learn something here anymore.

Comment: Common approach: Use CGI:Session to create a session. Store the "variables" in the session. Return the session id to the client in a cookie. The second script, being on the same domain, will receive the cookie.

Comment: Actually, this is CGI, and that's really just a wrapper around a bunch of really ugly environment variables. I _think_ your other script should inherit the environment as it's started in a subshell of the first one if you shell out to it. Thus, it should be possible to simply also `use CGI` there and load them all over again. I've never tested this, and don't have the means to do so right now, but if I remember the theory correctly this should work. It's not the variables you'll pass along, but it will share the same parameters.

Comment: As to how we're reacting to this kind of question: most of us here are professional programmers that have been working with Perl for a long time. If someone asks a very specific question, we usually don't question the reason, but in your case there is a lot of back story that sounds like a bad approach. So we suggest alternatives and point out the flaws. That's meant to be encouraging to learn more, and do things in a safer or more modern way.

Comment: You do also ask for the _best way_, which invites opinion, and that's off-topic. Three ways were mentioned here already that would answer the question and I know at least two more. The _best way_ imho is not to do this, though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that install-app-pl.cgi is a CGI program? Are you sure that it's not just a Perl command-line program? I mean, I see how it's named, but it seems very strange to call a CGI program using `system()` like that.

And the difference is crucial here. CGI programs access their parameters in a different way command-line programs.

If it really is a CGI program, then you have a few options:

- Make an HTTP request to it (using something from the [LWP bundle of modules](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl)).
- Use CGI.pm's debugging mechanism to call it the same way as you're currently calling it, but passing the CGI parameters like `foo=xxx&bar=yyy&baz=zzz` (see the [DEBUGGING section of the CGI.pm documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#DEBUGGING) for details). This, of course, relies on the program using CGI.pm and it feels a bit hacky to me.
- Ask yourself if the program really needs to be a CGI program if you're calling from another program using `system()`. And then decide to rewrite it as a command-line program. If you want both a CGI version and a command-line version, then you could move most of the code to a module which could be used by two thin wrappers which just extract the parameters.

A few other points about your code.

- Perl 5.6 (released in 2000) introduced a `use warnings` pragma. Most people now use that in place of `-w` on the shebang line.
- It seems weird to call the `header()` function before loading the CGI module that defines it. It works, because the `use` is handled at compile time, but it would be nice to re-order that code to make more sense.
- Similarly. most people would have `use strict` (and `use warnings`) as the very first things in their program. Immediately after the shebang line.
- `system()` returns the return value from the process. If your second program produces useful output that you want displayed on the web page, you should use backticks instead.
- If all of your output is going to be in a `<pre>` element, why not just remove that element and return a content type of "text/plain" instead?

**Update:** And I'd be remiss if I didn't reiterate what many people have already said in comments on your original question - this sounds like a terrible idea.